# Macro Button protected in protected worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to run a macro which creates a pdf which work fine. When the excel file gets signed, the excel file gets automatically protected.

Problem: I have a button on the worksheet which needs to be pressed to create the pdf documnet. However this can not be done because the button has also got protected and cant be press. Is there anyway around this?

However if i try save the excel file as manaully as pdf it works.

**Points to bear in mind**

If the worksheet gets unprotected the signatures get removed.

**Small around that will not delete the signatures**

If the excel sheet is saved as a **different name the signatures remain.**
So if i am able to get the button to work . The workbook could be saved as different name ( in macro), and then save as pdf which will contain signatures.

Answer (score 3):

Right click on the button and click on Format Control; go to the Protection Tab and untick Locked checkbox. It will then still be available when the sheet is Protected.

Comment: Tried that work around the button is still protected

Comment: An unlocked button can be pressed on a Protected Sheet in a Protected Workbook that has a Signature. Any lines in the VBA that try to make changes to the signed workbook will throw an error because it is read-only. Are you getting an error message or is nothing happening when you click the button? Are you sure the button works before protecting/signing the workbook? Are you sure you've unlocked the button?

Comment: Button Fully works when the workbook is not protect.  So when the signature is applied , I am not able to press the button at all.

Comment: Is your VBA code potentially turning protection on for the button/locking the button at runtime?